# Applescript shell script to folder with space

Tags: shell, applescript

I am trying to write a text file to a folder that contains space in the name. eg: folder 2

The first script that writes to folder works correctly
The second script that writes to folder 2 does not work correctly.

Edit:
I tried to use single quotes around the path and it works, if I hardcode the path. Is there a way to write to the folder without losing the ~ symbol?

```
    --this works
   do shell script "echo " & "the text" & " >> ~/Desktop/folder/text.txt"

    --this does not work
   do shell script "echo " & "the text" & " >> ~/Desktop/folder 2/text.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
do shell script "echo " & "the text" & " >> ~/Desktop/folder\\ 2/text.txt"
```

Note: When using `~`, which is the same as `$HOME`, in a `do shell script` and there is a *space* in the *pathname*, use a double backslash `\\` to escape the *space* and do not quote the *pathname* containing a `~`. In `bash` the *space* would only need a single backslash `\` to escape the *space*.

This works too:

```
do shell script "echo " & "the text" & " >> \"$HOME/Desktop/folder 2/text.txt\""
```